# Как в Unity из GameObject сослаться на скрипт, привязанный к нему?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
foreach (GameObject Player in affectedPlayers)
    {
        Player.GetComponent<PlanetConstraint>().TargetPlanet = gameObject;
    }
```

affectedPlayers это HashSet содержащий GameObjectы. Ко всем ним я привязал скрипт PlanetConstraint(на всех объектах в affectedPlayers он точно есть). Юнити выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
[image: сообщение об ошибке]

Как я понял, поскольку на GameObject нет такого компонента изначально, то Unity отказывается это компилировать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: GetComponent<PlanetConstraint>()

Comment: Простите, но эта информация доступна в официальной [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). Даже в Гугле находится по первым строчкам. Если не умеете искать нужную информацию - заниматься программированием Вам рановато.

Comment: это решение из документации не работает, даже после исправления кавычек, по ней как раз и писал, а в гугле тоже ничего нет. Если Вам удалось найти в гугле ответ, прошу поделиться ссылкой

Comment: А в текущем коде либо ошибка указывает не на представленную строку, либо в Player нет такого компонента, либо Player  это вообще обычный класс, который не отнаследован от MonoBehavior

Comment: А может быть где-то есть тип Player и он думает что это обращение статически к классу и надо написать с маленькой буквы

Comment: В целом можно воспользоваться отладкой, чтобы посмотреть что там точно в player и affectedplayers

Comment: Уже решил, спасибо большое